# mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, mysqli

This is connection string

```
global $db_connection;

$db_connection = false;

$db_connection = mysqli_connect($config['server'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
```

Function:

```
function lastInsertId() {
    return mysqli_insert_id($db_connection);
}
```

Getting error

```
mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: @JameyD connection is fine, as insert query is working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a global variable for your mysql connection you must specify the variable with `global` for it to be usable in a function:

```
function lastInsertId() {
    global $db_connection;
    return mysqli_insert_id($db_connection);
}
```

Comment: `$db_connection` is globally declared.

Comment: @abbas So then, to use it in a function, you must let PHP know it's a global variable by declaring it in the function as global : `global $db_connection;`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I have edited my question which shows global declaration.

Comment: Read again the answer of Jamey D.

Comment: @abbas you might want to read about global variables first. If you want to use a global variable inside a function you need to refer it there too. Jamey is right.

Comment: @abbas no, your declaration of `$db_connection` was fine, just add `global $db_connection;` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need function like:

```
function lastInsertId($db_connection) {
    return mysqli_insert_id($db_connection);
}
$db_connection = mysqli_connect($config['server'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
$id = lastInsertId($db_connection);
```

And when you are calling function pass connection object in argument.

EDITED : global function in php not working like they maybe works in other programming languages(eg. javascript). You must explicitly define global variable.

```
function lastInsertId($db_connection) {
    global $db_connection;
    return mysqli_insert_id($db_connection);
}
```

Comment: `$db_connection` is globally declared.